# Count core data attributes that fulfill a certain condition (SwiftUI)

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have created a core data entity with the following attributes (from `Item+CoreDataProperties.swift` file):

```
extension Item {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Item> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var likes: Int16

}
```

I am trying to return within `ContentView` a variable that shows the total number of `Item` that have more than 5 likes. What would be the best way to do this?

I've tried adding the following computed property, but it only checks whether the first item in the array fulfills the condition and I I'm not sure how to get it to loop over all of them.

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])

var item: FetchedResults<Item>    
var likesCount:Int {
            get {
                
                if item[0].likes > 5 {
                return 1
                }
                else {
                    return 0
                }
            }
        }
```

I was also reading about a method called `countForFetchRequest`, but it seems to only be for detecting errors and I'm not sure it applies here.

Many thanks! Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use [count(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506868-count) with a fetch request that has a predicate

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind giving a bit more info about how that would work? Super new to all this :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
 var countOfItems: Int {
  getCount()
 }
```

and then:

```
 func getCount() -> Int {
   var countOfItems: Int = 0
   let context = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
   
   let itemFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
   
   itemFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "likes > %d", 5)
   
   do {
      countOfItems = try context.count(for: itemFetchRequest)
      print (countOfItems)
   }
   catch {
      print (error)
   }
   return countOfItems
}
```